# PHP MVC Structure and its contents

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, structure

For the past few months I've been working with procedural PHP, and a week ago, I decided my next step would be in starting to learn Object Oriented PHP. I studied it, and came to the conclusion that I would use the MVC Model for my Object Oriented PHP. I watched a few hour long videos, as well as read many posts on it. After a while, I followed and made a MVC Skeleton, and then of course added to it. I'm wondering if this is correct and following the model, or if I did something wrong.

To explain a little bit, I split the 3 folders into 2 categories: Pages and Components. The pages would be for example, Register, Login and so on and components would contain logic for example. Navigation Bar, Footer, Pagination and so on. My code currently works and I don't see an issue, but I want somebody else's opinion on this.

The structure is split like this: [Image Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn6DK.png)

**In layout**, theres 2 components which are footer and header. The footer and header contain normal HTML tags.

Header:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Footer:

```html
</body>
</html>
```

All of the pages just contain normal HTML until there's something I need to use the PHP for, such as echoing user information and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The principle here is to seperate HTML from PHP. You should route calls to their correct destination aptly. Stick to these core principles and try to seperate the ‘controller’ from the ‘template’.

Not sure what you are expecting, but this is what I foresaw.